# How to access a entity class from twig page

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Suppose I have an entity class named `Userinfo` where the fields are `name`, `guid`, `status`...

So now from a twig page if i want to show all available `name` from the entity class `Userinfo`,  how i can do that.

as an example --- in the page there can a table where it will show -- name and status.

So from entity class `Userinfo` all the names and their status will be shown.

Can someone knows how to dynamically show the data into the twig page from an entity class, can you kindly give me an example if possible.

Comment: I'm gonna ask a stupid question here: I assume you have tried doing a `{% for ... %}` loop?

Comment: @Andrew yes i have tried doing that, but failed ...

Comment: Did you get any errors? Can you paste in the array or whatever entity you're using please?

Comment: @Andrew it is not returning anything and not showing any error as well, that's why i get confused and that's why i want to see the whole process if possible

Comment: Alright, fair enough. Now about that array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain and simple, you pass the collection to the template:

```
public function someAction()
{
    $usersInfos = $this->getDoctrine()
                       ->getRepository('YourBundle:UserInfo')
                       ->findAll();

    return $this->render('YourBundle:your_template.twig', array(
        'usersInfos' => $usersInfos
    ));
}
```

To render a table in `your_template.twig`

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>guid</th>
    <th>status</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for userInfo in usersInfos %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ userInfo.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ userInfo.guid }}</td>
      <td>{{ userInfo.status }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% else %}
    <tr>
        <h2>Empty!</h2>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Example

**Contoller**

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entities = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Entity')->findAll();

    return $this->render('YourBundle:index.html.twig', array('entities ' => $entities ));
}
```

**Twig**

```
{% for entity in entities %}

        {{ entity.name }}<br>

{% endfor %}
```